# Pull, Release and Update on Facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook, pull-to-refresh

How to perform the experiments proposed the facebook application to refresh the page (ListView) on Android ?

**1) Pull**

[image: pull]

**2) Release**

[image: Release]

**3) And Update**

[image: Update]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to copy/mimic that functionality? https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh